# How to access KaiOS native contacts data

Tags: javascript, web-worker, firefox-os, kaios

I've tried to access the contacts data store using a worker, it worked but it returns `0` data stores when I do:

```
navigator.getDataStores('contacts')
```

Does the native KaiOS contacts app even use a data store? How do I access the native contacts data in my app?

Comment: Do you use the Simulation or a real connected device?

Answer (score 0):

#### Datastore on FirefoxOS

The `navigator.getDataStores('contacts')` seems only supported on Firefox OS for Desktop, not on the version for Mobiles (Gecko), see the [docs](http://www.devdoc.net/web/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getDataStores.html). If supported it would return a `Promise` and not `0`.

#### How to use `mozContacts`

You can access the contacts using `navigator.mozContacts`.
This instance supports methods `find(searchOptions, callback)`, `getAll(callback)` and `save(contact, callback)`.

See also:

- archived Mozilla Boot2Gecko (B2G) repo on Github: [`gaia` search for `mozContacts`](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/search?q=mozContacts)
- Luxferre's [*FastContact*](https://gitlab.com/suborg/fastcontact/-/blob/master/js/contactmgr.js), lightweight alternative to stock KaiOS contact list app